# Working with JApplet with Menus

Tags: java, swing, menu, japplet

I'm having problems with my code.  The sub-menu for the (Music) menu should be a radio button type.

Here's my first code:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

public class AMBAT_FLAB1 extends JApplet implements ActionListener{

JMenuBar mainBar = new JMenuBar();
JMenu menu1 = new JMenu("File");
JMenu menu2 = new JMenu("Format");
JMenu menu3 = new JMenu("Background");
//for file
JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem("Open");
JMenuItem save = new JMenuItem("Save");
JMenuItem reset = new JMenuItem("Reset");
//for format
JMenuItem setFont = new JMenuItem("Set Font");
JMenuItem setColor = new JMenuItem("Set Color");
//for background
JMenuItem image = new JMenuItem("Images");
JMenuItem music = new JMenuItem("Music");
//submenu of music
JRadioButtonMenuItem play = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Play");
JRadioButtonMenuItem loop = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Loop");
JRadioButtonMenuItem stop = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Stop");

ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

//file chooser
//JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
//fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);

//text area
JTextArea myArea = new JTextArea(50, 50);
JScrollPane scrollingArea = new JScrollPane(myArea);

Container con = getContentPane();

public void init(){
    setJMenuBar(mainBar);
    mainBar.add(menu1);
    mainBar.add(menu2);
    mainBar.add(menu3);
    menu1.add(open);
    menu1.add(save);
    menu1.add(reset);
    menu2.add(setFont);
    menu2.add(setColor);
    menu3.add(image);
    menu3.add(music);
    music.group.add(play);
    //group.add(loop);
    //music.add(stop);

    open.addActionListener(this);
    save.addActionListener(this);
    reset.addActionListener(this);
    setFont.addActionListener(this);
    setColor.addActionListener(this);
    image.addActionListener(this);
    music.addActionListener(this);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

}
}
```

When I try to run it, the Music menu doesn't appear.  It changes to the Play (radio button).  Does the button group help?  When i tried to use the button group nothing happens.

Comment: same answer as on another Java Forum

Comment: @mKorbel

like this??::

group.add(play);

Comment: nobody could tell that is outdated tutorial http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html and 1st. examples http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/0440__JRadioButtonMenuItem.htm that I found around

Comment: i'd already read that tutorial. :( still can get it. when i tried to use the group.add(play);

Comment: id already read that tutorial. still cant get it :(

when i tried to use the group.add(play);, it does not work really. my Music menu will not appear. it overlaps with my Play radio sub-menu :(

Comment: BTW +1 for including the code.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image: AMBAT_FLAB1 on screen]

```
/* <applet code='AMBAT_FLAB1' width=220 height=100></applet> */
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class AMBAT_FLAB1 extends JApplet implements ActionListener{

    JMenuBar mainBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu menu1 = new JMenu("File");
    JMenu menu2 = new JMenu("Format");
    JMenu menu3 = new JMenu("Background");
    //for file
    JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem("Open");
    JMenuItem save = new JMenuItem("Save");
    JMenuItem reset = new JMenuItem("Reset");
    //for format
    JMenuItem setFont = new JMenuItem("Set Font");
    JMenuItem setColor = new JMenuItem("Set Color");
    //for background
    JMenuItem image = new JMenuItem("Images");
    JMenu music = new JMenu("Music");
    //submenu of music
    JRadioButtonMenuItem play = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Play");
    JRadioButtonMenuItem loop = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Loop");
    JRadioButtonMenuItem stop = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Stop");

    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

    //file chooser
    //JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    //fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);

    //text area
    JTextArea myArea = new JTextArea(50, 50);
    JScrollPane scrollingArea = new JScrollPane(myArea);

    Container con = getContentPane();

    public void init(){
        setJMenuBar(mainBar);
        mainBar.add(menu1);
        mainBar.add(menu2);
        mainBar.add(menu3);
        menu1.add(open);
        menu1.add(save);
        menu1.add(reset);
        menu2.add(setFont);
        menu2.add(setColor);
        menu3.add(image);
        menu3.add(music);
        group.add(play);
        group.add(loop);
        group.add(stop);
        music.add(play);
        music.add(loop);
        music.add(stop);
        //music.add(stop);

        open.addActionListener(this);
        save.addActionListener(this);
        reset.addActionListener(this);
        setFont.addActionListener(this);
        setColor.addActionListener(this);
        image.addActionListener(this);
        music.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    }
}
```

---

The mistakes in the code were basically:

- If Music had children, it had to be a `JMenu`, not a `JMenuItem`
- A `ButtonGroup` is a logical group (e.g. to make radio buttons out of a group of buttons), it is *not* a container.  So besides adding the buttons to the group, it is necessary to add them to the Music `JMenu`.

Comment: better would be to deleted my post +1

Comment: @mKorbel  Your code was nicer, with the `serialVersionUID` declared & the `@Override` notation. :)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson as you mentioned you are manage Java code in the TextPad, but IDE managed me how, where, why ..., I'm only push mouse_click to the yellow whatever, with intentions cleanup all possible warnings, that (sometimes) true IDE manages us :-)

Comment: @mKorbel Now I've upgraded to a 64 bit OS and have gone from (recently 2 to) 3.2, then to 4 Gig RAM (soon with 8), I have been thinking about giving TextPad the flick and giving one of the proper IDEs a run again.  See if I detest it less, with the 64 bit OS and a bunch of RAM.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your source code.  Try commenting out the line that is failing and recompiling. That should give you a bit more information in your interface (GUI).