# Calling class with swing menu and menuitem objects

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jmenu, jmenubar

I need your help :). This is my first post here. I am trying to create a menu bar as a seperate class for my JFrame that I will call from separate class MainBar. How can I do that? I tried with the code listed below and calling new MainBar() but I always get just my JFrame with Menu without items on it.

Do I miss a return statement here? All tips are appreciated. Thanks!

```
public class MainBar extends JMenu{

    public  MainBar() { //What is return from this method? Component?


    // Bar Menu
    final WebMenuBar mainBar = new WebMenuBar();
    mainBar.setMenuBarStyle(MenuBarStyle.standalone);

    // Bar Menu Items
    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    JMenuItem exitMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    fileMenu.add(exitMenuItem);

    JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
    JMenuItem cutMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Cut");
    editMenu.add(cutMenuItem);
    JMenuItem copyMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Copy");
    editMenu.add(copyMenuItem);

    JMenu viewMenu = new JMenu("View");
    JMenu settingsMenu = new JMenu("Settings");
    JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");

    // adding menu items to bar menu
    mainBar.add(fileMenu);
    mainBar.add(editMenu);
    mainBar.add(viewMenu);
    mainBar.add(settingsMenu);
    mainBar.add(helpMenu);

   // should I put here return statement like return mainBar; ?
}
```

}

Comment: At first glance, it looks like you're creating it in-line with the menu class itself.  Is there other code that generates a menu before this you may be seeing?  Check out this previous question for examples, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555677/working-with-japplet-with-menus

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No, this is the only code that generates JMenu and JMenuItems. If its in the same class with JFrame, its working and showing Menus and Items normaly. That example from link  is not helping me at all, different story :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I figured out the answer:

```
public class MainBar extends WebMenuBar{

public  MainBar() { 


// Bar Menu
final WebMenuBar mainBar = new WebMenuBar();
mainBar.setMenuBarStyle(MenuBarStyle.standalone);

// Bar Menu Items
JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
JMenuItem exitMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
fileMenu.add(exitMenuItem);

JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
JMenuItem cutMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Cut");
editMenu.add(cutMenuItem);
JMenuItem copyMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Copy");
editMenu.add(copyMenuItem);

JMenu viewMenu = new JMenu("View");
JMenu settingsMenu = new JMenu("Settings");
JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");

// adding menu items to bar menu
add(fileMenu);
add(editMenu);
add(viewMenu);
add(settingsMenu);
add(helpMenu);


}
```

Now when I call it from another class with MainBar mainBar = new MainBar(); it generates Menu Bar and all its elements. Thank you guys anyway!